# WMI Notfication and database mirroring

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi all I'm having a problem configuring a WMI alert that I would like to use with database mirroring. I'm running on Windows 2008 Enterprise X64 with Server 2008 Enterprise X64 also SQL Server has SP1 installed. Basically I click on alert select WMI after that I typed the below SQL statement

SELECT *
FROM DATABASE_MIRRORING_STATE_CHANGE
WHERE DatabaseName = 'testmove' AND
State = 8

I have also made sure the service broker is enabled for the msdb and all mirrored databases however I still can't get this to work basically the alert never fires. I'm testing with just the alert functionality I have not even added in the agent job yet. I tested this by right clicking on my mirrored database and forcing it to fail over. Any help with this problem would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Based on the query in your question, the event will fire only when there is an automatic failover (state = 8).  If you want the WMI event to file on a manual failover, as in your test, you need to also check for state = 7, which is the state of a manual failover.

To check for both manual failovers and automatic failovers, your query would read:

SELECT * FROM DATABASE_MIRRORING_STATE_CHANGE WHERE DatabaseName = 'testmove' AND State IN (7,8)

Additional information can be found here: [Database Mirroring State Change Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191502(v=SQL.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Which mode are you using: High Safety or High Performance? High Performance requires Forced Service.

"Mirroring is stopped on the mirror database using `ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET PARTNER OFF`. The mirroring database is then recovered using `RESTORE DATABASE <dbname> WITH RECOVERY`. When the principal server becomes available, mirroring would need to be reestablished, this time in the reverse direction." *Section 11.5.4 Failure Scenarios, SQL Server 2008 Administration in Action, Rod Colledge*

```
USE MASTER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE1] SET PARTNER OFF
RESTORE DATABASE [DATABASE1] WITH RECOVERY
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE1] SET PARTNER FORCE_SERVICE_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS
GO
```